# How to parse an XML from string

Tags: javascript, xml

I'm developing a cordova/phonegap app and I want to read an xml in order to show some data to user.

I found a way to get my xml file:

```
getXML.onclick=function(){
var url = 'http://....cloudfront.net/TestFile.xml';
var xmlhttp;
var x,xx,i;
if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
  {// code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
  xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
  }
else
  {// code for IE6, IE5
  xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
  }
xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function()
  {
  if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200)
    {
      x=xmlhttp.response;
      alert(x); // Here it shows my xml file
      for (i=0;i<x.length;i++) {
         alert(x[i]); // This shows letter by letter my file
      }
    }
  }
xmlhttp.open("GET",url,true);
xmlhttp.send();

}
```

So, how should I parse my xml file?

Thanks

Comment: 1) I think one can drop IE6/IE5 support nowadays 2) If you have control over the data: take JSON instead of XML. 3) Modern browsers have an XML parser on board, but that just gives you an XML Document - I guess that is not exactly what you need? 4) jQuery has a parseXML method you could use as well.

Comment: I don't have control over the data. How could I use jQuery to parse the xml?

Comment: May almighty google be with you: http://api.jquery.com/jquery.parsexml/

Comment: God bless almighty google and bless you @Christoph. You don't know how much you helped me. ;)

Comment: Thank you & you're welcome! You can either accept Pablo's answer if it helped you or write an answer on your own how you solved the problem and then accept it, so the SO community knows your problem is solved. Either way is fine. Have a nice weekend.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use this in order to parse your xml from a string:

```
if (window.DOMParser) {
    parser=new DOMParser();
    xmlDoc=parser.parseFromString(txt,"text/xml");
}
else // Internet Explorer
{
    xmlDoc=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLDOM");
    xmlDoc.async=false;
    xmlDoc.loadXML(txt); 
}
```

Where txt is your xml string